# According to Trinitarians, can beings other than God take on other natures?

Tags: trinity, nature-of-man, persons-of-the-trinity, incarnation, hypostatic-union

The standard Trinitarian position is that a 'person' of the Triune God 'took on' or 'added' a human nature. So once that occurs, this person has **both** a fully human and a fully divine nature.

This question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26737/can-we-at-some-point-take-on-a-divine-nature) asks whether *humans* can take on a divine nature. The only answer there suggests 'no'.

Have Trinitarian theologians addressed whether other beings can 'take on' or 'add' natures *outside of* divinity? For example, could a cat 'take on' a dog nature, and become both fully cat and fully dog? Or is this something that cannot happen?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "nature"? For example, when you ask whether a cat could 'take on' a dog nature, do you have in mind a cat with [shapeshifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapeshifting) abilities, like [Mystique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_(character)) from the X-Men?

Comment: Why do you say "[The only answer there](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/26739/1787) suggests 'no'."?

Comment: @Geremia The answer there says "Humans can never become God". ?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Whatever Trinitarians mean by 'nature' when saying a person of the Trinity 'added a nature' (or what have you) is what I mean by 'nature'. Does Mystique 'take on' a dog nature if she shapeshifts into a dog (and then get rid of that nature when she shapeshifts back)? Or does she merely appear like a dog while retaining her cat nature? I am not familiar with the X-Men enough to say whether that fits the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

#### The natural order God has created

**Can beings other than God take on other natures?**

The short answer: **This can only happen if God, the creator of all natures** (human, animal, plant, light, bacteria, Covid-19 virus, chemical elements, rocks & minerals, angels & demons, heavenly things like stars, etc.), **allows it to happen**.

BUT, the answer seems to be **NO**:

- Both our best *philosophical* investigation (through **God given** reason) and our best *scientific* investigation (possible *only* because **God seems to guarantee a certain *stability of the nature of things*** once a thing acquires existence) say ***NO***, since we never see other beings other than God take on nature *by their own power*.
- God did not positively reveal that "adding" nature is what God plans to do in creation.  ("revelation" is, by definition, knowledge that we cannot know by our own unaided faculties)
- When we observe something "unnatural", in our Christian thought world we immediately think of either magic (facilitated by humans), miracle (caused by God or angels as His agents), demonic manifestations (caused by demons), or unexplainable power of nature.  The Bible is explicit that humans should **not** practice magic, and that demonic manifestations **are not God's design** and can be countered by exorcists.  Whether some magical / demonic phenomena can be interpreted as "adding on nature" is left to debate.  Again, the point is **what God allows to happen**.  For non-miracle phenomena, we are simply told that this is *not* part of his design for creation.

#### Removing corruption IS promised

What God DOES plan for us is either creating a brand new heaven & earth, or transforming the current heaven & earth into a place where there is no more death and corruption.  This is more of a **change of nature** from mortal to eternal, from bodies that is dying "naturally" to ones that are glorious, like the resurrected bodies we will have.

#### Sharing in divine nature IS promised

2 Peter 1:3-4:

> <sup>3</sup> His divine power has granted to us all things that pertain to life and godliness, through the knowledge of him who called us to his own glory and excellence, <sup>4</sup> by which he has granted to us his precious and very great promises, **so that through them you may become partakers of the divine nature**, having escaped from the corruption that is in the world because of sinful desire.

[The answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/26739/10672) to the question "Can we at some point take on a Divine Nature" provides the right interpretation for the above promise, that ***it's a *sharing*, not an *adding on* divine nature***.  The nature of our substance as human being created in the image of God does *not* change substantially but *restored* (effect of the Fall removed), *completed* (some theologians like St. Irenaeus speculated that even the prelapsarian Adam was premature like a baby), and *glorified* (possessing a better body like Jesus after resurrection) after death.

Comment of the answerer:

> We should note that the text never says we become anything. It merely says we are "sharers in the divine nature." Thus, the real question is "How are we sharers in the divine nature?" and certainly not "Do humans become God?" If God is spirit (in nature), and the Holy Spirit is indeed spirit, and God, don't we share/ participate in the divine nature when the Holy Spirit indwells us? See 2 Cor. 13:14: ἡ κοινωνία τοῦ Ἁγίου Πνεύματος.

The most important take away is that it is God's **initiative** and **power** to let us share His divine nature, and only through His **method**.  All we can do is say "yes, I want it" and "I receive the gift".  It's not like we have to discover and practice a certain *technique* to acquire/share the divine nature (such as those proposed by other religions or by magic practitioners or by cults that give us demonic powers).

#### God the Son assuming human nature is a special case

What about God adding on human nature?  Remember, that this is *our* theologizing so that revelatory data can be understood philosophically.  It is an approximating concept of the reality over which we have no power.  Only God can do this, which is reasonable to believe because God is the author of all natures observable in creation.  Just because Shakespeare can appear in his own play acting his own character, God can enter the world to fulfill his prophecies about Jesus.  But a Shakespearean character cannot do anything that he is *not* scripted to do.  Going back to philosophy of nature, a created being only has power accorded to its nature by God.

Comment: Why do you mention "God the Son assuming human nature" when the question excludes that case?

Comment: @Geremia it's only for comparison, emphasizing that the "adding nature" in Jesus case is special and should not be overgeneralized into a general ability that a created being can have.  It also highlights that even if God allows it to happen, it requires God's power and permission, which is not given in the cases of magic and demonic interference (the only 2 possible scenarios where "adding nature" may happen).

Answer (score 1):

Angels can take on human nature apparently:

> Do not neglect to show hospitality to strangers, for thereby some have entertained angels unawares. (Hebrews 13:2 ESV)

Comment: We should distinguish between taking on "human appearance" and fully adding human nature like Jesus.  Remember that one heresy was that Jesus only appeared human (Docetism), so it's perfectly reasonable to see this verse as describing "angelic docetism" or accomodation.